# Pregnant platy behavior

Tags: behavior, fish, breeding, pregnancy

I have an orange platy and I suspect she is pregnant and switched her from the main 60 gallon to an old 20 gallon tank, but would eat until I put the the male platy with her. Is this normal? I wonder if she was stressed by herself.

[image]